# Could the Daedalus wallet use less space on laptops?

Tags: daedalus, decentralization

I use my laptop to store some of my ADA. Unfortunately, running low on disk space, I cannot afford to store the whole ADA blockchain locally.

What are the options for people like me that need to run the Daedalus wallet on low disk space?

Answer (score 3):

Do you *need* to run the full Daedalus wallet? On low-storage system I'd suggest looking at Yoroi which is a 'light wallet' that doesn't require its own local node.

Comment: Besides running trustless, do you have a set of features that the Daedalus wallet supports that the Yoroi wallet does not support?

Comment: @LaX here's a good overview https://iohk.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360026058573-Daedalus-wallet-and-Yoroi-wallet-overview

Comment: That overview is misleading, as there are many inconsistencies. Daedalus is far from fully trust-less, it forces you to connect to IOHK nodes, so in this regard it provides the same level of trustfulness as Yoroi. Also, Yoroi browser extension also support multiple wallets.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I have found for now on macOS is to **move part of the Daedalus files to an external volume**.

To do that on macOS:

1. Ensure you went through Daedalus onboarding (to let it create its directory structure)
2. Close the Daedalus wallet (even if it isn't done syncing the Blockchain)
3. Open a terminal, and run:

   ```
   export EXTERNAL_DRIVE_PATH=/Volumes/<enter the drive name here>/Daedalus/chain
   mkdir -p "$EXTERNAL_DRIVE_PATH"
   mv "~/Library/Application Support/Daedalus Mainnet/chain/immutable" "$EXTERNAL_DRIVE_PATH/immutable"
   ln -s "$EXTERNAL_DRIVE_PATH/immutable" "~/Library/Application Support/Daedalus Mainnet/chain/immutable"
   ```
4. Open the Daedalus wallet, and let it synchronise normally

These commands move the `~/Library/Application Support/Daedalus Mainnet/chain/immutable` folder to an external drive and alias it back so that Daedalus knows where to write.

This solution might break in future versions of Daedalus, and I would only recommend it as a temporary workaround. Also, I assume disconnecting the drive with Daedalus still open would somehow break it but I haven't tested this scenario.

Comment: This is working in Ubuntu over LAN. The immutable can be in NAS and accessed. I am not aware of the security implications.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows environment, this page on the Cardano forum has the solution. It works!

https://forum.cardano.org/t/storing-the-cardano-blockchain-on-another-hard-drive-flash-drive/3699